# Using z-index to sort SVG objects, parent containers and text

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like to overlay SVG objects on top of a container, but the text in that container must be accessible by the user's mouse (in other terms, put the text forward without it's parent following, vice-versa). This is my current situation:

I currently have 2 SVG objects, with a style of `z-index: 2`. Then, I have a `<div>` container with a style of `z-index: 1`, and finally, the div contains a child `<text>` element with a style of `z-index: 3`. With my understanding of how z-index works, the SVGs should overlay the container, but the text should stand out.

However, it appears the text follows its parent z-index and gets overlaid by the SVGs. **How should I proceed to keep the text above the SVGs, while its container remains behind?**

Comment: Please create a [mcve] rather than just describing the problem in text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set your `<text>` element to `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;`.  Are you doing that?  If not it won't work.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}

text {
  font-size: 40px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <text>Some text here</text>
</div>

<svg>
  <circle cx="150" cy="75" r="75" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```